# NA values as conditions on a IF statement in R

Tags: r, if-statement, null, dataset

My goal is to categorize the rows on my dataset depending on the values of two different dates.

```
if(!exists(MY_DATA$Date_1) & exists(MY_DATA$Date_2)) {
  MY_DATA$NEW_COL <- c("Category_1")
} else {
  MY_DATA$NEW_COL <- c("Category_2")
}
```

But it isn't working, I'm currently trying a simplified version as follows:

```
if(!exists(MY_DATA$Date_1)){
  MY_DATA$NEW_COL <- c("Category_1")
}
```

However, it seems that this only reads the value on the first row, and it either gives me a column with all values as `Category_1` or no column at all.

Also I have tried this with `is.na()`, `is.null()` and `exists()`.

Comment: Welcome to SO!  Please include an example of your data with `dput` for a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Comment: `if` is not vecotrized like you are using it. You want the `ifelse` function: `MY_DATA$NEW_COL  <- ifelse(!exists(MY_DATA$Date_1),"Category_1","Category_2")`

Comment: `exists(MY_DATA$Date_1)` is only meaningful if: `MY_DATA` is exactly one row; `Date_1` contains strings; and those strings point to variables in the local environment or within the search path. Otherwise, perhaps you need `"Date_1" %in% names(MY_DATA)`.

Comment: Also, the only time it is appropriate to use `&` (single) in an `if` clause is if you wrap it in some aggregating function like `any` or `all`, otherwise it *might* work as you need but can very easily fail. Why? `&` returns a vector of length 0 or more of logical, whereas `if` **requires** length exactly 1.

Answer (score 0):

> However, it seems that this only reads the value on the first row, and it either gives me a column with all values as `Category_1` or no column at all.

This is because `if` statement requires a vector of length 1. When given a vector with length more than 1, it will only read the first member to make the decision `TRUE` or `FALSE`.

The `ifelse` function can accept vector argument and will return a vector of logical `TRUE`/`FALSE`. It may be suitable for your needs.

---

Rephrasing originally a comment by @r2evans, the use of `exists()` is to check if a variable is already defined in the R environment. `exists()` takes a character vector of length 1 as argument, otherwise it will check only the first member.

```
a = 1
b = 1
exists("a")
[1] TRUE

exists(c("a", "b"))
[1] TRUE

exists(c("ab", "a", "b"))
[1] FALSE
```

However it's worth noting that `exists()` does not check if a value is inside a vector. If you are trying to check if a value is in a vector, you'll want operator `%in%` instead.

---

The solution will largely depend on your precise implementations.

p.s. This is originally intended as a comment, but is too long as a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for your support, `ifelse` did the trick.

The following worked for me:

```
   MY_DATA$NEW_COL  <- c("Category_2")
   MY_DATA$NEW_COL  <- ifelse(!is.na(MY_DATA$Date_1),"Category_1","Category_2")
```